# How Can I import a project in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded this example: [link](https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/Personal-Information-MVC)

Unzipped, but I can't inport in Netbeans because no globe icon before the file icon.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#NBDAG445. But I would be very cautious of using as example a project that doesn't use a standard build tool like gradle or Maven, and pushes its compiled .class files to the repository. A quick glance at the code confirms my fears: it's awful.

Comment: In other words: this is more of an example what you can do the wrong way. Consider not wasting your time with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the .settings , .classpath and .project folders from the project you have downloaded from github as these folders are created when this project was imported in eclipse IDE. To import this in Netbeans first delete these folders then load this project as new Netbeans web application project.

Comment: New -> Project -> Web application with exciting source? Error message: Project Folder already contains "build" folder.

Comment: delete build folder as well because we can create this folder after doing build from netbeans..

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will work. But here is the alternative and easy way.

In Netbeans clik on **Files** > **Import Project** > **Eclipse Project**.

Now select **Import Project ignoring Project Dependencies** and choose source folder of your Eclipse project and the destination folder to import.

Click on **Finish**. That's it now the Netbeans will take care of importing and converting Eclipse project into Netbeans project.

PS: You can also import project from Eclipse workspace if any exists.